# How to install and configure Hummingbird DM Server, DM Client

Tags: dms, dm, opentext

I want to install Hummingbird DM 5.1 for Record Management. For that I have installed DM Server, RM Server and RM Client. But it seems this is not completed.

Do I have to install DM Web Server and DM Admin Tool?

Thanks

Prakash

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite:
1. Net Framework 2.0 or above
2. Installer: \Server\DM Extensions Server Setup-English\Setup.exe

1. Run the \Server\DM Extensioins Server Setup installer
2. Leave the default installation media location (ie. \Server\DM Extension Server Setup-English)
3. Leave the default Installation Destination Folder (ie. C:\Program Files\Hummingbird\DM Extensions)
4. This part is where the integration happens.

   - DM Application Integration\Microsoft Application\Microsoft Excel\Microsoft Excel Active Integration\via ODMA > with Front-End Profiling.
   - DM Application Integration\Microsoft Application\Microsoft Word\Microsoft Excel Active Integration\via ODMA > with Front-End Profiling.
   - DM Application Integration\Microsoft Application\Microsoft Powerpoint\Microsoft Excel Active Integration\via ODMA > with Front-End Profiling.
   - DM Application Integration > Windows Explorer DM Extension.
   - DM Viewer
5. Then click Next to install.
6. Select the Server name. Then click Next.
7. A must to restart to apply installation.

Issues up to this moment:
This installation setup is using Office 2000 and theres a problem opening excel files, the rest are OK. (word, ppt and pdf)
Office 2007, it is reciprocal. There is no issue with Excel but problems opening word and ppt records.

In case you or someone is able to debug this integration problem. Do drop me a message.
Thanks and I hope this helps.